# "Haven't" vs. "hadn't"

Tags: meaning, differences, tenses, present-perfect

Are there any differences in meaning between the two sentences?

> 1. We hadn't left the place yet; we will be there in 10 minutes.
> 2. We haven't left the place yet; we will be there in 10 minutes.

Comment: (1) This question presumes that only one of them can be grammatical. This is false, since they're both fine.

Comment: Why do you think either would be incorrect? They have different _meanings_, but they are both perfectly ordinary idiomatic English.

Comment: (2) This question gives no context or purpose for a sentence. Sentences cannot be judged outside of a context.

Comment: #1 is odd and I don't see how it's correct.  No matter how I try, I can't even crowbar it into a usable scenario.  IMO, only #2 is correct. (John or Colin - how would #1 possibly be used?)

Comment: The original sentences made sense but were later edited.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is for ELL to deal with this.

Comment: @Kris - if you type it like this: `[ell.se]` (that is, in square brackets, with the .se suffix), then a link will automatically be embedded in your comment: _This question appears to be off-topic because it is for [ell.se] to deal with this._ That might help newcomers who don't recognize the ELL abbreviation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct. The difference is that *hadn't* is is in the past tense while *haven't* is in the present tense.

EDIT (due to your edit)

In context, *haven't* is the grammatically correct sentence. *Hadn't* would not make sense as the order of events ought to be preserved.

Nevertheless, *hadn't* would make sense if something happened between the two events and the point at which they had yet to leave were mentioned by the other individual(s) in the conversation.

For example:

> We hadn't left yet when you called earlier. We'll be there in ten minutes.

Answer (score 2):

As we were leaving the restaurant the waiter called out, "Sir, you haven't paid your bill yet". Just then it occurred to me I hadn't been to the bank.
HAVEN'T present tense, HADN'T past tense.